# JobInfoSchedulerService from firebase-android-sdk crashing with DeadSystemException

Tags: android, firebase

I am facing crashes in my android app w.r.t. `firebase-android-sdk`. I use the following firebase components in my app:

- `firebase-crashlytics` - `17.3.1`
- `firebase-config` - `20.0.3`
- `firebase-analytics` - `18.0.2`

Here is the stack trace of the crash in firebase `JobInfoSchedulerService`:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4180)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:232)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7604)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

The app does not use any of the API(s) in `com.google.android.datatransport` which comes with Firebase. Please help me understand and fix the underlying cause of this issue.

Comment: Im having the same issue with Xamarin and packages "Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 120.1.7" and "Xamarin.Firebase.Analytics 117.4.1" Did you managed to resolve this issue?

Comment: No, not yet at least. Going to use the latest firebase libraries to see if that fixes the issue.